# ClassNotFoundException while upgrading project from Java 8 to 11

Tags: java

I am working java version upgrade from 8 to 11 and getting below exception after upgradation. This exception is thrown by one of the internal project jar which we are using.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.istack.localization.Localizable
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 93 more
```

We are using following dependency in our project. Is it specific to this dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/istack/localization/Localizable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078766/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-sun-istack-localization-localizable)

Comment: Thanks for quick response! I have gone through this article before posting my question but it didn't help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have excluded following dependency which is referred from one of the internal project/dependency and issue got resolved.

```
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
```